# Install the socket.io offline

Tags: windows, node.js, github, socket.io, npm

When am trying to install socket.io using npm, am getting the following errors.

[image]

Recently our Indian government has blocked the access to github. So I do not currently have access to github. [see the news here](http://thenextweb.com/in/2015/01/02/india-lifts-blocks-github-vimeo-dailymotion-weebly-others-remain-banned/)

So I was trying to install the socket.io offline. Downloaded the socket.io.master from [here( Thanks @Vitaliy Zurian for this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z90x1if7q8bm8z3/socket.io-master.zip?dl=0)

```
npm install socket.io.master
```

Even then its failed because it's fetching the dependencies from git.

so my questions are as follows

**Is there a Step-by-step guide on how to install socket.io offline?**

Or

**Is there any alternate installer for socket.io?**

Comment: Does npm install get the source from git? I would've thought npm just has it stored somewhere.

Comment: @cgf we are not able to access git. Its been blocked by our Government.  Any alternative way to install socket.io?

Answer (score 1):

As a temporary solution, you can download this library from elsewhere to your local machine, and then use the local path for installing it:

```
npm install /path/to/your/local/socket.io --save
```

For more information refer to the [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

Comment: oh. i did not thought of installing it offline. Thanks for the answer..

But I did not find any other site than git-hub where I can download this library. Do you have got any?

Comment: @Mitz Here you go https://www.dropbox.com/s/z90x1if7q8bm8z3/socket.io-master.zip?dl=0

Comment: I've tried with the downloaded folder. Even then I'm unable to install the same. Its trying to download some dependencies from git. I'll edit my question and post the screenshot of it. Please have a look.

Comment: @Mitz Well, there are obviously more dependencies on every package. I would suggest you to rent a VPS somewhere outside of India (check Digital Ocean or AWS) - and do your stuff there.